# RequireJS loading issue (with packages)

Tags: package, requirejs, amd, amplifyjs

I am using RequireJS 2.0.6. And sometimes I have a laoding issue with one of my library (amplifyjs).

Project:

```
libs/
    amplify.js
    handlebars.js
    jquery.js
    require.js
packages/
    core/
        main.js
index.html
main.js
```

My main.js:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': '../libs/jquery',
        'amplify': '../libs/amplify',
        'handlebars': '../libs/handlebars'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'amplify': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'amplify'
        },
        'handlebars': {
            exports: 'handlebars'
        }
    },
    packages: ['core'],
    baseUrl: './packages/'
});

require(['jquery', 'amplify', 'handlebars', 'core'], function() {
});
```

Index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="main" src="libs/require.js"></script>
```

75% of time it works but sometimes I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/aa/test/packages/libs/amplify.js 404 (Not Found) 
Uncaught Error: Script error
    http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

The path is wrong! But I cannot figure out why this happens ? And why only sometimes ?

(I am pretty sure it has to do something with the package, but I have no idea why it does that)

Comment: Are you sometime calling amplify as a dependencies without using the path alias?

Comment: No, I just refresh the page and this error comes on. The only call of amplify is in the require method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out another way to do it and it works!

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        libs: '../libs'
    },
    packages: ['core'],
    shim: {
        'libs/amplify': {
            deps: ['libs/jquery'],
            exports: 'amplify'
        },
        'libs/handlebars': {
            deps: ['libs/jquery'],
            exports: 'handlebars'
        },
        'core': {
            deps: ['libs/amplify', 'libs/handlebars']
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: What did you change that made the difference? Declaring the packages before the shims, the more generic path handling, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> (I am pretty sure it has to do something with the package, but I have
>   no idea why it does that)

The word `packages` refers to the standard CommonJS, because requirejs supports loading modules that are in a [CommonJS Packages](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.1) directory structure and the modules themselves should be in a module format that RequireJS can understand.